# Angular 2 - Get cookie from response

Tags: angular, typescript, cookies

I need help, I'm trying to get the cookie from the response, and I can't find a way, I'm pretty new with tsc and ng2.

This is the ng2 http post

```
return this._http
    .post('http://demo...', body, { headers: headers })
    .subscribe(
        (response: Response) => {
            this.storeToken(response);
        }, (err) => {
            console.log('Error: ' + err);
        }
    );
```

This is the server response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=A099CC4CA7A25DFBD12701630A7DC24C; Path=/pbcp/; HttpOnly
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 17 Feb 2017 04:08:15 GMT

32
{"status":"OK","message":"User is Authenticated."}
0
```

I'm confused, because I can't see it in headers array...

Result of `console.log(response)`

[image: Response from Chrome console]

Result of `console.log(response.headers)`

[image: Headers array from Chrome console]

..., but i can see it in cookies section.

[image: Cookies section in Chrome]

Thanks!

Comment: try this res.get("set-cookie")  and let me know

Comment: also try this for multiple cookies let resHeader: Headers = res.headers;
resHeader.getAll('set-cookie');

Comment: Hi @Vinay, first, thanks for your time. Your suggestion didn't work because the response don't have a header with that name, please, see my edited post.

Comment: try to print this console.log(response); and than console.log(response.headers) this will print headers which are coming from the server. and make sure you are sending headers from server.

Comment: @Vinay I've edited the original post with your request, thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Well, after some research, I've found two issues from my side.

**First**, the cookie was set OK, but I was looking for it in the wrong place. All this time I was looking it under my `localhost:3000` domain, and the cookie was stored correctly under `http://demo...` domain, that, that is the proper behavior. I could see it in `chrome://settings/` ==> Show advanced settings ==> All cookies and site data... ==> and filtering by the remote host like following:

[image]

---

**Second**, I forgot to use `withCredentials: true` in the rest of request headers also, in order to include and accept the cookie automatically.

```
authenticate(username: string, password: string) {
    var body = `{"username":"${username}","password":"${password}"}`;
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true });

    return this._http
               .post('http://demo...', body, options)
               .subscribe(
                   (response: Response) => {
                   this.doSomething(response);
               }, (err) => {
                   console.log('Error: ' + err);
               });
}
```

Thanks @All for your responses and time!

Comment: With this answer could you access the Set-Cookie header with `response.headers`?

Comment: there is no need to access the Set-Cookie, cause it's added automatically for each request. So just set `withCredentials: true` and everything should works fine

Comment: This answer saved me so much trouble. The problem for me was the back-end's address(0.0.0.0) and this pointed me out to that problem. So I changed the back-end to 127.0.0.1 and the cookie worked!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using the angular2 http module to contact the server which will return an observable with the server response.

You can use the response if you subscribe to it:

```
//...
http.post(...your content...)
 .take(1) // optional: depending on your needs you could .take(x) this to just take a certain number of responses and then terminate the subscription in order to not have a "hot Observable" lying around
 .subscribe(response =>{
      .console.log(response);
    // if I am not mistaken "response.headers" should contain the "Set-Cookie" you are looking for 
 });
```

You could also transform the observable to a Promise:

```
http.post(...your content...)
  .toPromise()
  .then(response=>{
     console.log(response);
     let headers = response.headers;
     console.log(headers);
  })
  .catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

In certain response cases you might need to transform it using response.json() to retrieve and object.

Hope this helps. If it isn't what you are looking for give me some more details and I'll try to help.

Comment: Hi @jparg, thanks for your time, I'm using a post like you've posted, but this didn't work because when I inspect headers array, I don't see the "set-cookie' on it. Please, see my updated post.

Comment: Okay that is odd. If you try to get the cookies with: headers.getAll("set cookie") I assume you get back an empty array then?

Comment: No, I'm getting `null`