# access the set-cookie from the response header and store it in browser cookie (csrf issue) angular 2

Tags: angular, cookies, http-headers, csrf, angular2-services

I am trying to set the X-CSRF-TOKEN in the header by taking the value from the SET-COOKIE Header of the response in the Auth service....

To do this I have configured an interceptor in angular2 by extending the Http service from the Http module. And this is following code snippet...

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpService extends Http {

    constructor(_backend: ConnectionBackend, _defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
        super(_backend, _defaultOptions);
    }

    request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.intercept(super.request(url, options));
    }

    get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        alert('get');
        return this.intercept(super.get(url, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options)));
    }

    post(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> { 
        alert('post');
        console.log(url, body, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options));
        return this.intercept(super.post(url, body, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options)));
    }

    put(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.intercept(super.put(url, body, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options)));
    }

    delete(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.intercept(super.delete(url, options));
    }

    getRequestOptionArgs(options?: RequestOptionsArgs) : RequestOptionsArgs {
        if (options == null) {
            options = new RequestOptions();
        }
        if (options.headers == null) {
            options.headers = new Headers();
        }
        options.headers.append('Accept', '*/*');
        options.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        options.withCredentials = true;
        return options;
    }

    intercept(observable: Observable<Response>): Observable<Response> {
        return observable;
    }
}
```

So when I do this automatically after getting the CSRF-Token from the set-cookie header in the response of the Auth service, it is added as a cookie to other subsequent requests as I have given withCredentials "**true**".

Now I need to send one more header named "X-CSRF-TOKEN" in the subsequent request and value for the header should be the CSRF-TOKEN cookie value. For this, I am using Angular2 feature XSRFStrategy to inject the cookie value to that Header. The below is the following code....

**AppModule**

```
export class AppCSRFStrategy implements XSRFStrategy {
    constructor( private _cookieName: string,
                 private _headerName: string){ }

    configureRequest(req: Request): void {
        console.log('trying to set the header');
    }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [  BrowserModule,
              HttpModule,
              AppRoutingModule,  
              NgbModule.forRoot(), 
              AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
                apiKey: '***********************'
              }),
              CustomerModule,
              AppSharedModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [ {
      provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
      useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>'
    },  UserService, 
        AccessGuard,
        CookieService, 
        { provide: XSRFStrategy, useValue: new AppCSRFStrategy('CSRF-TOKEN', 'X-Csrf-Token') },
        { provide: Http, useFactory: httpClientFactory, deps: [ XHRBackend, RequestOptions ] }
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
```

My Problem is the cookie from the response header is not getting stored in the browser cookie and also the cookie as http_only : false and secure : false.... Please help Thanks in advance....

Plunker added : https://plnkr.co/edit/opERHKHPPk1AcVsTfF38?p=preview

Similar issue spotted : [Angular 2 - Get cookie from response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42289817/angular-2-get-cookie-from-response)

Comment: did you get the solution ?