# .Net Framework Web API FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, cookies, forms-authentication

I have an Angular 8 project which calls a Web API to login. The Web API project is built with .Net Framework 4.8, and is hosted on a different domain. To address CORS, I have the following in the Web.Config file (in the system.webServer area):

```
   <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Host, Connection, Accept-Encoding, User-Agent, Referer, Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, X-Auth-Token, If-None-Match, Accept-Language, _headersMap, withcredentials"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

I have also specified Forms authentication in the web.config file, in the system.web area, and specified a SameSite cookie value of "None", so the Angular site can pass the cookie to the Web API site,like this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms cookieSameSite="None" requireSSL="true" timeout="50000000" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

In my login method, I am calling FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie if login is successful:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/LaborLevel/Login")]
[ResponseType(typeof(LoginDto))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Login(LoginDto loginDto)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    return BadRequest(ModelState);

  try
  {
    var login = await dataSvc.Login(loginDto);
    if (login.Success == true)
    {
      // set auth ticket
      FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login.EmployeeNbr, true);
    }
    return Ok(login);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    return HandleError(ex);
  }
}
```

Running the solution in Visual Studio 2019, when I look at the login call in Chrome's Network tab, I see that the Response Cookies collection contains a cookie named ".ASPXAUTH", as expected:

[image]

However, when I look at the cookies saved to my web browser after calling the login method, I don't see any .ASPXAUTH cookie saved. And when I subsequently try to call a Web API method annotated with the [Authorize] attribute, I get a 401 access denied error.

In my Angular application, I am setting withCredentials = true in the httpHeaders collection used in the post method of the HttpClient, but since the cookie is never getting saved to my browser, I don't see how it can do any good.

What am I doing wrong? How to I get the cookie saved to the browser and passed to the Web API on subsequent calls?

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share the raw response as **text** rather than as a screen shot?  See [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) for why.  That being said, you posted your question at `2020-06-24 17:50:53Z`, and the image shown displays `Expires / Max-Age 2020-06-24T17:50:34.000Z`, i.e. 19 seconds before you posted your question.  Could the cookie have expired on arrival?  Or, could you have cookies blocked in your browser?

Comment: The response is a json object, which does not contain cookie information. I don't know how to view raw text of a cookie in a response - if you can  tell me how, I will.

Comment: As to your (interesting) point about the expiration time, I change the web.config file to specify a large timeout, so the expiration time is now in the year 2115, but still no change. No cookie saved to browser, and call to test secured method fails with 401. (I have updated the question with those changes.)

Comment: (And cookies are not blocked in browser - I get lots of them, just not this one.)

Answer (score 0):

I *finally* figured this out (only wasted most of a day).
The problem was that I was not setting "withCredentials" to true in my RequestOptions.

The second part of the answer here showed me what I was doing wrong:
[Angular 2 - Get cookie from response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42289817/angular-2-get-cookie-from-response)