# How to save an httpOnly cookie in an Angular application

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, cookies, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to save an httpOnly cookie returned by an ASP.NET Core API with a jwt token in an Angular application, but as far as know (and I could verify that with some tests), it is not possible to save it via Javascript, so I can't do something like that:

```
this.httpClient.get("https://localhost:5001/token", {withCredendials: true}).subscribe(result => {
  //logic to extract cookie from result
  document.cookie = cookie;
});
```

This is my controller code:

```
[HttpGet("token")]

public HttpResponseMessage Token()
{
   //some logic to get the token
   var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("token", token);
   cookie.HttpOnly = true; //Without that line the JS code works and I can see the cookie in Chrome DevTools 
   cookie.Secure = true;
   var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
   response.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });
   return response;
}
```

My Angular app is running on https://localhost:4200 and my API in https://localhost:5001

So, how can I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42289817/angular-2-get-cookie-from-response

Comment: Hi Chris, this is not working for me, my Angular app is running on localhost:4200 and my API in localhost:5001, int he advancaed cookie settings Im able to see just the information about 4200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing it wrong in the API side, instead of returning the cookie in the HttpResponseMessage I needed to add the cookie in the Response of the HttpContext:

```
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("token", token, new CookieOptions { HttpOnly = true, Secure = true })
```

In that way the Set-Cookie header of the response is set and now it is working fine.